# Google Apps Script Fails on "Service timed out: Spreadsheets"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Not a programmer but have mangled Scripts from this site and others to make life easier.

Script below previously ran successfully but now fails with the following every time... Service timed out: Spreadsheets

Anybody got some insight on cause and possible workaround.

```
function importData()
{
var sourcefile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx............xxxxx');
var sourcesheet = sourcefile.getSheetByName('MASTER');
var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A2:AD');
var sourcedata = sourcerange.getValues();

var targetfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('yyyyy............yyyyy');
var targetsheet = targetfile.getSheetByName('2018_IMPORT');
targetsheet.getRange(2,1,sourcedata.length,sourcedata[0].length).setValues(sourcedata);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue? Have you verified that the file you are trying to open still exists and you have permission to access it?

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details like if you are the owner of the spreadsheets or if they are shared with you by someone that you meet or not, and if you are able to open them by using Google Sheets. Also add the textual error message (usually error messages include the code line number).

Comment: You should clarify a bit about the size and validity of the imported range. Note that your stated import - `A2:AD` - probably includes a lot of empty rows that you really don't need to bother with.

Comment: Hi and thanks for feedback... to answer some questions... both files exist and are within same domain.  I am owner of both.... source file tracks "events" per location by on site teams (21 Location Tabs).  These tabs are consolidated onto a master Tab (nightly).  Data is mix of text, numbers and dates.... who, what, when, where, how many etc etc.  Data is pulled from Master Tab (currently ~13K rows) nightly to update a "Report" file.  Code does not appear to have errors.... Service times out.